# Can someone explain the overall plot device of Quiet Earth (massive spoilers)?

Tags: quiet-earth

In the 1985 movie, Quiet Earth, the protagonist finds himself apparently the only man on Earth. Later, he finds:

> two others who, like him were at the moment of death. He further determines that this is all due to an American experiment. Here's where I get a little fuzzy...was it that an entirely different reality was created and these folks were shunted to it, or did truly everyone else get wiped out? The ending, where the protagonist is shunted to a THIRD existence, seems to bear out the alternate reality existence...does this mean that the events are experienced only by the characters in the movie, and everyone else is just fine back in reality prime? Or did everyone get wiped out?

Which one is it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quiet_Earth_%28film%29

Comment: I don't see the answer to my question there.

Comment: ^^ It just says that it's left deliberately ambiguous. I don't have an opinion of my own, but - wikipedia is always right all the time, right? o.o

Comment: Heh. I did think that the bit about purgatory was thought-provoking.

Comment: "To create is to suggest.  To define is to destroy."  J. Michael Straczynski quotes this often, and reminded us of it often on Usenet while he was making _Babylon 5_.  Many times a writer or filmmaker wants something like that to be ambiguous to force viewers to think about it and arrive at their own conclusions.

Comment: @TangoOversway, yeah, but come on, what really happened?

Comment: @Sam: That's for you to decide.  Just like figuring out exactly what a black monolith is.

Comment: @TangoOversway, it's the opening to a wormhole.

Comment: @Sam: Then why no wormhole on the Moon or on prehistoric Earth?

Comment: We should probably pose this question on its own. If you accept the novel as canon to the movie, it's pretty clear what the monoliths are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At 1:21:01 in the film we see a mild version of "the effect" take place, roughly analogous to a pre-shock before an earthquake. All three of the survivors are thrust into alternate versions of Earth, two with drastically differing gravity and one where gravity seems to distort. None of them can see the others and until the effect passes none of them can interact with each other.

It's therefore likely that each time the effect takes place, an alternate Earth is created. Those who're unprotected (e.g. by being dead at the precise moment the original effect) remain in a stable dimension, presumably unaffected. Those who happen to be dead at the time of the effect are thrust into an increasingly unstable pocket dimension. If they somehow then regain consciousness they will find themselves alone on a "Quiet Earth"

---

From a "Voice of God" perspective, Writer and Director have both stated that the ending was ***intended*** to be ambiguous. In his commentary on the Umbrella Entertainment DVD release, writer/producer Sam Pillsbury [states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quiet_Earth_(film)),

> "...*we all thought it was quite simple; I mean, our intention was
>   just that, what happened was, he died at the moment of the effect for
>   a second time and he's now found himself in another world, what the
>   hell's he gonna do...", he then says, more or less jokingly, that
>   director Geoff Murphy being 'a Catholic or lapsed Catholic, (it) may
>   well have been something to do with purgatory, and y'know, you being
>   trapped in cyclical and going back into having to relive your thing
>   until you work out your karma, (something; possibly 'if I'm not')
>   mixing my metaphors; anyway, enigmatic is good, I think, to a certain
>   extent...*"

Comment: Is the "unprotected" line from the film itself? Otherwise it seems quite odd to speak of the unprotected being left unaffected in a stable dimension.

Comment: @Jontia - The term protected isn't from the film. I'mjuat using it to explain that non-alive people don't seem to be affected.

Answer (score 3):

I always thought that Zac had reached the conclusion (ahead of his companions) that - if the only people that lived past the experiment *being started* were people that were dying at the time - then the only way to survive the *experiment ending* would require dying again. Hence why he crashes the truck into the station - he ends the experiment and simultaneously kills himself, effectively 'killing' Joanne and Api. I think goes some way towards explaining the reaction of Joanne and Api when they realise what he's doing. But instead he has failed to understand the consequences of his actions again, and finds himself somewhere even more extraordinary.

I'll also add that, if you like the movie, you should definitely read the book. It's quite different in some ways, but I think a New Zealander would get more out of it than a non-New Zealander, on account of the way it focuses more on the rift between Maori and Pakeha, and the way it 'checks off' locations in New Zealand.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  So you're saying that this is the only Earth, and everyone else is gone?  Not that this is an alternate world that only the three of them were transported to?

Comment: I confess I hadn't thought deeply about that. It could be either though, couldn't it?

Comment: That's cool, I didn't realize that there was a book. I'll check it out.

Comment: I realise I didn't really answer the original poster's question, so in light of that, I'll add that the ending of the book is different from the movie, and perhaps makes the question posed a bit of a moot point.
The book is very good - one of those books you read, and then it keeps preying on your mind, so you read it again. I eventually bought a copy because of this.